# What is the proper way of catching an error from an Observable in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I am following a tutorial on this link [here](http://www.adonespitogo.com/articles/angular-2-extending-http-provider/).

The author is doing something here that I don't quite understand. In the catchAuthError method he passes the services own instance as `self`, but he does not use that variable in the method itself.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Request, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService extends Http {

  constructor (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token'); // your custom token getter function here
    options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    super(backend, options);
  }

  request(url: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
    if (typeof url === 'string') { // meaning we have to add the token to the options, not in url
      if (!options) {
        // let's make option object
        options = {headers: new Headers()};
      }
      options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    } else {
    // we have to add the token to the url object
      url.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    }
    return super.request(url, options).catch(this.catchAuthError(this));
  }

  private catchAuthError (self: HttpService) {
    // we have to pass HttpService's own instance here as `self`
    return (res: Response) => {
      console.log(res);
      if (res.status === 401 || res.status === 403) {
        // if not authenticated
        console.log(res);
      }
      return Observable.throw(res);
    };
  }
}
```

In the comment it says:

> we have to pass HttpService's own instance here as `self`

Why is this necessary and how should I catch errors in this situation? What is the proper way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing

```
return super.request(url, options).catch(this.catchAuthError(this));
```

or

```
return super.request(url, options).catch(this.catchAuthError.bind(this));
```

or

```
return super.request(url, options).catch((err)=>this.catchAuthError(err));
```

are practically the same thing, you are creating a closure in the last 2 and in the 1st one you are giving the `this` that refers to your component. But you are right that it is unnecessary in this case because it is not used.

the `res` in `return (res: Response) => {` equals to the error object in my third example.

---

The author may have thought about using the `this` instance someway inside the super class but in my opinion this is just a confusing example and can be simplified to this:

```
return super.request(url, options).catch((error)=>this.catchAuthError(error));
```

```
private catchAuthError (error) {
      if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) {
        // if not authenticated
        console.log(error);
      }
      return Observable.throw(error);
    };
  }
```

Comment: I got error: EXCEPTION: Observable_1.Observable.throw is not a function. Do I have to do: import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';?

Comment: I think `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';` is enough as it says in the documentation. There might be an issue with your typescript configs :| There's a similar issue on github:https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1866

Comment: Thanks! Btw do you know why he adds the headers both in the constructor and in the requests? Is it not enough to add it in the requests? Or perhaps just in the constructor?

Comment: @Alex but in the constructor it is giving the options to the super class also. If you want to add other headers after instantiating the http perhaps that could be the usage

Comment: I don't quite understand. It seems like there is no point in chaning headers in request, when we do it in constructor.

Comment: @Alex well me neither :-) btw this is not the angular way of inheritance. Take a look at: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#useclass-mdash-the-class-provider-

Comment: It says: The alternative could implement a different strategy, extend the default class, or fake the behavior of the real class in a test case. I am extending the default class. I don't understand what you mean :)

Comment: @Alex scratch my last comment. The author is doing something similar